# Download attachments PDF with Microsoft Exchange Server WebServices

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, pdf, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to download attachments PDF from emails. The problem is, when it download the PDF from the selected message, the PDF is always 0 kB (I'm sending the file so I know it and should be 1 MB).

Here is my code:

```
foreach (Item item in findResults)
{
    PropertySet props = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.Attachments);
    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id, props).Result;

    if (message.Subject.Contains("MyFilter"))
    {
        foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
        {
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

            // Load the attachment into a file.
            // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
            fileAttachment.Load(Path.Combine(foldpath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + attachment.Name));
            listnamePDF.Add(foldpath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + Convert.ToString(i + 1) + attachment.Name);
        }

        message.IsRead = true;
        message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve, true);
        FindItemsResults<Item> UpdateResults = exchange.FindItems(f.Id, SearchFilter, view).Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Do you get any exception or you simply get zero length file? Is your code surrounded by Try...Catch block? I would recommend to watch HTTP communication with some tool e.g. Fiddler if possible or catch the response when calling the `fileAttachment.Load()` method.

Comment: If you check the size property of fileAttachment what does that show ?